# After unzipping text files the format of contents are changed

Tags: files, zip

I zipped a few text files and sent as attachments to my email.
After extracting the text files, their format was changed.

Before:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

After:

```
line1line2line3
```

Is there a way to keep the original format after unzipping?

Command used:

```
zip file.zip *.txt
```

Comment: Are you looking at linux text files on a windows system? If yes, you'll need to replace `\n` with `\r\n` (or use a good editor like Notepad++)

Comment: @Panki, Yes you are right Linux text files am trying open in windows. Yes in Notepad++ and Wordpad  it is in same format opened.Can you please let me know where I can replace this /r/n ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Panki you are trying to open Linux text files on a Windows system.

**Short answer:**
What you want is save those text files with CRLF line termination (Read the long answer) used by Windows.
To do this open the file with gedit (The official text editor for Gnome).

1. At the top right corner hit the 3 horizontal lines
2. Save As...
3. At the Very bottom you should see a "menu" called *Line Ending*
4. Choose *Windows* and hit Save.

You should be fine now.

**Long answer:**

Every OS (for the most part) uses a different Escape sequence for the newline character

For reference:

- Windows uses CRLF (\r\n) -hex value=0d 0a
- MAC OS uses CR (\r) -hex value= 0d
- Linux uses LF (\n) -hex value= 0a

So when you transfer a files from one OS to another, in your case from Linux to windows the text editor expects `\r\n` but gets `\n`. As a result it appears like you are missing Newline characters. But that's not the case.

And of course, there is a solution to that. You can use modern text editors that take into consideration all line terminations. E.x. Notepad++, VScode, atom and many more.

You can check what line termination techniques are being use by utilizing the command `file`.

```
$ file file*
file1: ASCII text
file2: ASCII text, with CR line terminators
file3: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

All 3 files contain just the word "test". But from the above we conclude that

- file1 uses LF (linux)
- file2 uses CR (MAC OS)
- file3 uses CRLF (Windows)

You can also see the differences at the text itself by utilizing `od`

```
$ od -t x1 file1
0000000 74 65 73 74 0a
0000006
$ od -t x1 file2
0000000 74 65 73 74 0d
0000006
$ od -t x1 file3
0000000 74 65 73 74 0d 0a
0000010
```

Notice the difference at the end.